# How do you drive a 1 watt LED?

Tags: lm317

I want to build a 1 watt led driver,  the led requires 350mA@3.2V approximately.

1. I bought a LM317( 0.5A and 1.5A versions) for this purpose but I can't figure out the schematics of the LM317 and since I burn a lot of stuff so I decided to ask here first.
2. How much would the efficiency be?

My power supply: 2A@5.2volt-DC

Comment: You put it in your car, turn over the engine, shift into drive, and then enjoy your drive with your LED.

Comment: @horta That's taking the LED on an adventure, not exactly driving it though. But close enough.

Comment: @HarrySvensson I'm more curious about where he's wanting to drive his LED to. Maybe his LED has a hot date. Maybe with a 5 Watter?

Comment: Easiest thing would be just put a resistor in series with the LED. 2V / 0.35A = 5.7 Ohms. Maybe use 5.9 Ohms. At least 1 Watt power rating for the resistor. Not efficient but easy.

Comment: To get any more efficient you would need to use a switching regulator of some sort.

Comment: You need a 3.6 ohm between pins 1 n 2 of lm317.  Google for lm317 as current source. Very standard circuit. https://diyaudioprojects.com/Technical/Current-Regulator/

Answer (score 2):

Use an LED DC-DC driver IC. They're cheap, and you won't be shedding so much power in the the regulator. This one would work well: https://www.diodes.com/products/power-management/led-drivers/low-voltage-dc-dc-led-drivers/part/PAM2804

Another benefit of using this kind of regulator is that they set *current* in the LED, not voltage. Thus they eliminate the need for a load resistor.

If you use a linear regulator like the LM317, the total power loss (regulator and the load resistor) will be (5.2-3.2V)*0.35A = 0.7W, not a small amount of loss (41%, or 59% efficiency.) This is true regardless of how you use the regulator (constant-current or constant-voltage.)

One more thing: The LM317 has a high dropout voltage, about 1.6V for that current. This leaves just 0.4V of margin for it to operate the LED.

Comment: Thanks in advance! So much useful information, I shall burn and through all lm317s to trash without feeling guilty LoL

Answer (score 2):

I deleted the answer using the LM317 as current regulator as it will not work as **regulator**.

According the datasheet of Texas Instruments:

> **7.4.2 Operation With Low Input Voltage**
>   The device requires up to 3-V headroom (VI – VO) to operate in regulation. The device may drop out and OUTPUT voltage will be INPUT voltage minus drop out voltage with less headroom.

The head room in this case is only 5.2 V-3.2 V = 2 V
In this case, you could also (or even better) use one or few<sup>(1)</sup> resistors to give the required voltage drop.

Simulating in LTspice, you would need a 0.68 Ω resistor instead of a 1.25 V / 0.35 mA = 3.6 Ω resistor

So, regarding regulation and efficiency, better use a LED DC-DC driver as hacktastical suggests.

<sup>(1)</sup>A few resistors to distribute the power dissipation.